# Implementing push notification in a chat app

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, onesignal

I am building a chat feature using firebase Realtime database where an integer variable stores a number (int online) which when a chat is opened by person A it adds 1 to the database and then if another person B comes online and opens the chat then it adds another 1. So, if the number is 2 I know that both are online and active in the chat app so no need to send push notification.

But the issue that I am facing now is that if a user closes the app without pressing the in-built back button of the chat app (which when pressed subtracts 1 and becomes 0 when both users are inactive), then the number in the database is not changed which causes error in the push notification logic as when Person A sends a message, the code assumes Person B is online. How could this be solved? Please someone help me understand how push notifications generally work?

Answer (score 3):

First off all sending push notifications is completely FREE. The only costs are made by the the backend (cloud functions) that executes the code to send them.

Secondly. If your users are in the app no push notifications will be shown. Even if you would like to show some in your app you would need to handle the `onMessageReceived` to show something to the user while he is in the app.

That means there is no need for you to do the thing you try to do. Just send all messages as if no user is in the app. It would even cost you more to check for each user if he is online or not and send the messages only if he is offline than just to send them to everyone.

I would recommend to read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) a little bit to get a deeper understanding of FCM and if you have any specific questions we can all help you with it :)

Comment: Hey Tarik, thanks for the answer, it helped me. However, if we want to prevent push notification of messages sent by B when the user has opened the chat screen of B, then how do we go about it? the two ways I figured out was one, to update the backend for active chats and before sending notification to check if the reciever id is in the activeChat. Another is client side approach, which is storign the active chats on local storage and blocking (?) the notification if the chat is active. 
How would you go about this?

Comment: Do you have a scenario where the user is using multiple devices and you don't want to send push on phone if he is in web online?

Comment: not yet, I am only launching the app rn.

Comment: If users use a single device you don't need to do anything. If they are in your app and a push is send they won't get it shown.

Comment: thanks, but i wanted push notification to be displayed also when the app is running on foreground, however not when that specific chatscreen is open, exactly how whatsapp works. though for now, i went ahead with the apporach of checking active chat id and storing the same in storage.

Comment: Then you can use in App `onMessage` event like here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive